# How can I connect 1 machine to 4 routers to configure the routers at once

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I currently enter configuration details in to routers for a customer. Is there a way that my instructions can configure multiple routers at a time instead of just one?

I have automated this process using a mouse recorder program but I can only do one router at a time on one windows 7 pc.

I dont want to buy more PCs.

The routers do not go on line in this process. I just want to be able to configure 4 of them at a time. 10 of them at a time would be great!

All the routers will have the same ip address and I do not want to make any changes to the routers configuration to enable this process as this would defeat the object of the exercise.

I imagine if it is possible that the answer may be with a server with multiple network cards and NIC Teaming with a virtual interface but I am lost !

Please can you tell me how I can configure multiple routers at a time instead of just one.

Could a virtual machine or virtual machines or a virtual network be used to connect to the 4 routers and/or sepearte NICs and what would be the steps to make this work?

Comment: Does the router model allow you to save and load configurations?

Comment: How are you connecting the routers to your PC? If you are connecting them via an IP network, and they all have the same IP address, I don’t see any way you can have more than one of them active on the network at once. If you’re connecting to them via serial lines, you should be able to do several simultaneously if your PC has multiple serial I/O ports.

Comment: The router is connected to the windows 7 pc by ethernet cable. I enter configuration details via the GUI Thanks for the serial line suggestion and I will look into this  but i would have to start from scratch again. How can I connect 4 routers with the same IP address to the computer?

Comment: Using a hub does not work but would it be possible to use a modified ethernet cable. One RJ45 at one end and 4 RJ45 at the other end so the computer whilst communicating to one router is actually communicating to 4 or will the mac addresses or anything else prevent this communication.

Comment: The router model does allow me to load and save configuartions but there are a lot of routers and I have automated this process and now want to be able to do it to multiple routers at once

Comment: Normally in NIC Teaming the Virtual NIC will decide which NIC to use. But rather than load balancing is there away to instruct the Virtual NIC to broadcast the information to all NICs. So im thinking about 4 network cards each connected by an RJ45 cable to a router. The routers will have the same IPaddress but diffrent MACs. They will not be functioning as routers just reciving configuration information. Can this work and what are the steps to do it?